# Are these two implementations of Bag different monads?

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming

I am not an expert with functional programming.  What I know is that the bag data structure satisfies the definition of a monad.  There are two different implementations of Bag: one with linked lists, B1, and one with hash maps, B2.  In B2, you are storing integers that are the multiplicities. I want to know:

1. Are B1 and B2 ever treated as different monads?
2. If yes, what do we know about the monad transformer from the linked list monad, B1, to the hash map monad, B2,where you add all the instances and store an integer?

Comment: I would say that B1 and B2 are not treated as different monads. Their types are the same and their methods always give the same results. The difference is only in the implementation. This is like saying that 10 + 20 is equivalent to 25 + 2 + 3 but the implementation is different.